# SVG: Easiest way for shadows without filters

Tags: svg, filter, shadows, drop-shadow

I'm developing an app which uses SVGs as graphical resources (for better scaling and crisp graphics). The programming part is just fine but the SVGs must not contain filters due to some programming reasons. The only filters I need are shadows like the one below.

[image: Shadow with filters]

The Question:
What's the easiest way to create a similar looking shadow without using filters using Inkscape or Illustrator?

Comment: Can you use some blur?

Comment: Can you code the shadows using CSS?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini No since blur is a filter as well
@AndrewH It seems like CSS is not supported as well.

I did some further research and found out that only the following is supported:
`<circle> <clipPath> <defs> <desc> <ellipse> <g> <line> <linearGradient> <marker> <mask> <path> <polygon> <polyline> <rect> <solidColor> <stop> <svg> <switch> <symbol> <title> <use> <view>`
and the following is supported with limitations:
`<image> <text> <textPath> <tref> <tspan> <pattern> <radialGradient> <style>`
any <filter> element is not supported at all.
I hope I dont have to use gradients.

Comment: Sorry for adding another comment. A minute after clicking 'Add Comment' I got the message that CSS might work (although it wasn't mentioned anywhere in documentation). I'll give it a try and add an answer / edit the question.